# Stuck in infinite inversion loop Coq

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I have an inductive relation as shown below titled  *suffix*. I am trying to prove the related theorem  *suffix_app*. My general idea is to use that fact that  *suffix xs ys* to show that xs is either equal to ys or that it is some series of elements  *cons*'d onto ys.

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive suffix {X : Type} : list X -> list X -> Prop :=
  | suffix_end : forall xs,
          suffix xs xs
  | suffix_step : forall x xs ys,
          suffix xs ys ->
          suffix (x :: xs) ys.

Theorem suffix_app : forall (X: Type) (x:X) (xs ys: list X),
  suffix xs ys -> 
  exists ws, xs = ws ++ ys.
Proof.
  intros.
  inversion H.
  - exists []. reflexivity.
  -
```

However, when I use inversion, there's no way of actually ever "arriving" to the term that is equal to ys. Hence, I am stuck at the point currently seen in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof simply follows by induction on any of the structures, example:

```
Theorem suffix_app (X: Type) (xs ys: list X) :
  suffix xs ys -> exists ws, xs = ws ++ ys.
Proof.
induction 1 as [|x xsp ysp hs [zs zeq]]; [now exists []|].
now exists (x :: zs); rewrite zeq.
Qed.
```

For practical reasons thou you may want to use a different, computational version of suffix.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay in responding. Indeed this works. However, why must I call induction 1 with the as clause to get the hypothesis zeq? I was just experimenting without the as clause and where I expected to find zeq(but with an automatically generated name from Coq) there was no such hypothesis hence the proof was unsolvable with the as clause. Sorry, I don't quite understand this aspect of Coq.

Comment: I am not sure I follow, you should get the same results whether you use the `as` clause or not. Be sure you are calling induction on the right thing! Note, if you use automatically generated names you will suffer a lot when Coq decides it wanted to change the naming scheme and thus all your proofs are not valid anymore.